# Scipy optimise minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, minimization

I am trying to solve the optimization problem with 4 variables.
I have to give constraint in the `scipy.optimize`,
the constraint is `x[1] < x[2] < x[3] < x[4]`.
Is there any methodology to solve this problem in `scipy.optimise`

Comment: `<` and `>` are not possible in optimization, only `≤` and `≥` (related to the mathematical concept of compactness). Sometimes, we can fudge: `x[1] < x[2] <=> x[1] ≤ x[2] - 0.0001`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a variable transformation, for example,

`y[1]=x[1]`

`y[2] = x[2]-x[1]`

`y[3] = x[3]-x[2]`

`y[4] = x[4]-x[3]`

Then you can use constraints like `y[2] > 0`, `y[3] > 0`, etc.